# How to pass json data like {"en":"600","ru":200,...} to view from Controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using vectormap that Get data with this Format {"en":"600","ru":200,...}
I retrieve data in controller and make a list of VectorMapViewModel and pass into the view by json result and get that data with jquery in view ,but I can't create this Format for vector map.

```
public class VectorMapViewModel
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public int CountryVisit { get; set; }


}

 [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult RequestVisitorsVectorMapData()
    {
        var countrydata =new List<VectorMapViewModel>();
        using (var db = new AppDbContext())
        {

            var results = db.Countries;
            countrydata.AddRange(results.Select(country => new VectorMapViewModel
            {
                CountryCode = country.CountryCode,
                CountryVisit = country.ViewCount
            }));
            return Json(countrydata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

 <script>

    $(window).load(function() {
        $.getJSON('/Home/RequestVisitorsVectorMapData/', function(data) {


            $('#world-map').vectorMap({
                map: 'world_en',
                backgroundColor: null,
                borderColor: '#000',
                borderOpacity: 0.25,
                borderWidth: 0.5,
                color: '#e7eaeb',
                enableZoom: true,
                hoverColor: '#16a085',
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
                scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#006491'],
                selectedColor: '#000',
                values: data
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map your data to a dictionary:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult RequestVisitorsVectorMapData()
{
    var countrydata = new List<VectorMapViewModel>
    {
        new VectorMapViewModel { CountryCode = "us", CountryVisit = 100},
        new VectorMapViewModel { CountryCode = "ru", CountryVisit = 200},
        new VectorMapViewModel { CountryCode = "ir", CountryVisit = 2000}
    };

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (var item in countrydata)
    {
        dictionary.Add(item.CountryCode, item.CountryVisit);
    }

    return Json(dictionary, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This dictionary will be serialized to:

```
{"us":100,"ru":200,"ir":2000}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $.getJSON('/Home/RequestVisitorsVectorMapData/', function(data) {
        var struct = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
           struct[data[i].CountryCode] = data[i].CountryVisit;
        }

        $('#world-map').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_en',
            backgroundColor: null,
            borderColor: '#000',
            borderOpacity: 0.25,
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            color: '#e7eaeb',
            enableZoom: true,
            hoverColor: '#16a085',
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
            scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#006491'],
            selectedColor: '#000',
            values: struct
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but struct return data like {en=600} but i want {en:600}

Comment: The code would give you {en:600}. All it is doing is creating an object with those properties.